# Docker image is not visible through the Remote Docker API

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have docker image hosted in Bintray. I build local image using the following e.g.:

```
FROM foo.bintray.io/bar/server:0.5.10
```

Building an image from Bintray image works and I can see it in the list of images: `docker images`:

```
> docker images
...
foo.bintray.io/bar/server   0.5.10 ...
```

However, when I access the same docker using the remote API:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://127.0.0.1:2375/images/json"
curl -X "GET" "http://192.168.99.100:2375/images/json" (on OSX)
```

this image is missing!!! It's simply not there.

What?!

Comment: What's `http://192.168.99.100:2375` and what it has to do with Bintray or running local docker commands?

Comment: It's boot2docker VM ip address on localhost.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to send a GET request to a Docker daemon instead of using the Docker client?

Comment: Nevermind - see the answer, figured finally. Docker CLI behaves differently then Remote API, that is the bottom line. Maybe you can add some checks on Bintray for names and valid chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the wrong naming (not related to bintray in any way).

The image is named `bar/server` and that is wrong - no `\` is allowed in the name. Remote API does not allow names to have this char (and some others). Nevertheless, docker CLI accepted it and worked fine.

Once when I renamed to the `bar-server`, it worked.